# Interpreting Django server request log

Tags: django

When I start the Django server, I can see the logs in the terminal:

```
[31/Jan/2015 14:06:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30697
```

What does the last number signify?
('30697' in this example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the size of the response (in bytes).